# python exec takes no kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

```
help(exec)
```

Gives me

```
Help on built-in function exec in module builtins:

exec(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)
    Execute the given source in the context of globals and locals.

    The source may be a string representing one or more Python statements
    or a code object as returned by compile().
    The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
    defaulting to the current globals and locals.
    If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
```

Though

```
>>> exec("print(a)", globals={'a':1})
```

gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: exec() takes no keyword arguments
```

How should I pass additional arguments to the python `exec` function?

Comment: As positional arguments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

globals() is a function that stores all information related to the global scope variables of the program. (Global symbol table)

An approach to address your requirement is as follows:

```
In [1]: a = 1
In [2]: exec("print(a)", globals())
        1
```

Or if you want to use `kwargs`, then it should be a function as follows:

```
In [1]: def val_a():
...:     return 10

In [2]: exec("print(a)", {'a': val_a()})
        10
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @juanpa.arrivillaga in comment, this is a *positional* argument :

```
exec("print(a)", {'a':1})
```

returns

```
1
```